# Printing content of Array in Array of Array (Angluar.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have code like here : http://codepen.io/fadynoor/pen/RPWxad

Please see the page1.html on this part:

```
<div>
    <p>content of parrot : {{ctrl.contents[0].zoo[1].parrot}}</p>
    <p>content of tiger : {{ctrl.contents[1].zoo.tiger}}</p>
    <p>content of zoo : {{ctrl.contents[0].zoo}}</p>
</div>
```

I just want the content of parrot and tiger array be printed on the screen like the zoo does. but I don't have any idea how to call the array properly.

And after that, I want to make list of the content.
will this be right to do it?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="desc in ctrl.contents[0].zoo.parrot">{{desc}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to display the second element of the `zoo` array, which only has 1 element.

`<p>content of parrot : {{ctrl.contents[0].zoo[0].parrot}}</p>` works ;)

Edit to address second question: yes.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="desc in ctrl.contents[0].zoo[0].parrot">{{desc}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, i thought that the parrot and the monkey are 2 different element of the zoo.

Comment: `zoo` is an array, while `parrot` and `monkey` are objects inside the first element of the `zoo` array

Comment: and i've succeed on making the list. yeay!